# Numpy get maximum value based on XYZ

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to read an CSV file with some XYZ data but when gridding using Python Natgrid is causing an error: `two input triples have the same x/y coordinates`. Here is my array:

```
np.array([[41.540588, -100.348335, 0.052785],
   [41.540588, -100.348335, 0.053798],
   [42.540588, -102.348335, 0.021798],
   [42.540588, -102.348335, 0.022798],
   [43.540588, -103.348335, 0.031798]])
```

I want to remove XY duplicates and get the maximum Z value. Based on the example above, I want to remove any minimum values of this array:

```
np.array([[41.540588, -100.348335, 0.053798],
   [42.540588, -102.348335, 0.022798],
   [43.540588, -103.348335, 0.031798]])
```

I have tried using `np.unique`, but so far I haven't had any luck because it doesn't work with rows (only columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `numpy` way, sorting first by `Z`, then finding the first of each unique `X` and `Y` pair, and indexing:

```
a = np.array([[41.540588, -100.348335, 0.052785],
   [41.540588, -100.348335, 0.053798],
   [42.540588, -102.348335, 0.021798],
   [42.540588, -102.348335, 0.022798],
   [43.540588, -103.348335, 0.031798]])

# sort by Z
b = a[np.argsort(a[:,2])[::-1]]
# get first index for each unique x,y pair
u = np.unique(b[:,:2],return_index=True,axis=0)[1]
# index
c = b[u]
>>> c
array([[ 4.15405880e+01, -1.00348335e+02,  5.37980000e-02],
       [ 4.25405880e+01, -1.02348335e+02,  2.27980000e-02],
       [ 4.35405880e+01, -1.03348335e+02,  3.17980000e-02]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use `pandas`, you can take advantage of `groupby` and `max`

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame(arr).groupby([0,1], as_index=False).max().values

array([[ 4.15405880e+01, -1.00348335e+02,  5.37980000e-02],
       [ 4.25405880e+01, -1.02348335e+02,  2.27980000e-02],
       [ 4.35405880e+01, -1.03348335e+02,  3.17980000e-02]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas via sorting and dropping duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

res = df.sort_values(2, ascending=False)\
        .drop_duplicates([0, 1])\
        .sort_values(0).values

print(res)

array([[  4.15405880e+01,  -1.00348335e+02,   5.37980000e-02],
       [  4.25405880e+01,  -1.02348335e+02,   2.27980000e-02],
       [  4.35405880e+01,  -1.03348335e+02,   3.17980000e-02]])
```